# abrt-server: Undefined variable outside of [[ ]] bracket

Tags: python, centos, incron

I am trying to run my python scripts from incron triggers, but I'm having this error

```
abrt-server: Undefined variable outside of [[ ]] bracket
```

Now I'm not sure if this is with my python script because if I run it independently, it does work as expected.

I'm checking /var/log/messages but I see the same general error

And running service incrond status -l shows the same message

Is there anyway I can find the specific line where the error was detected? (Will making abrtd verbose mode help?)

Comment: I tried to debug my script by commenting all the lines and uncommenting 1 by 1. import os, doesn't post an issue. But for some flippin' reason, when I do import pandas as pd, I get an error. same as above. I have installed pip already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the details about the error can be seen at /var/spool/abrt/{most updated Python folder}